# Can't execute pgAdmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4, postgres-9.6

I installed Postgres9.6 ver And pgAdmin4 was installed together.
But It is return message "The application server could not be contacted" When i execute pgadmin.

I tried to download and install pgAdmin4 from web.
But have not changed anything.

I couldn't get anything Although I searched google about the message.

I Set System Path, And Postgres is running in my local.
But pgadmin don't start up.

Do somebody know about this?
Thank you.

---

update:

i found this
[question](https://superuser.com/questions/1097581/can-not-connect-to-pgadmin-server).

I think that is same my problem which got 3 good vote even if the message is different a little.

So i'm trying do that, But can't run `setup.py`.

I installed python. and run `pgAdmin\web\setup.py` with cmd as admin.
But fail with message of

> from flask import Flask No module named 'flask'

thank you.

Comment: If you are running windows then try this installer.
https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v1.4/windows/

Comment: thank you comment, I tried that installer, but it is still happening.

Comment: did you perform clean install ? 
I mean did you deleted all the directories created by pgAdmin & uninstalled pgAdmin4 completely from your system before installing it?

Comment: n33rma // I didn't that, So i tried again after uninstall old version. But it was not solved. So i'm now using pgadmin3. But i will try again to install pgAdmin4 after all postgres and pgadmin delete. if it will work. i comment here. thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem with pgAdmin 4 1.5 on Windows 10 Professional. The solution was simply to delete `%appdata%\pgAdmin` which was created by an earlier version. On systems other than Windows, there probably is a pgAdmin directory in your user directory. Of course, all session settings etc. are gone after deleting this.

Answer (score 9):

We got the same issue. so no need to any change in the file.

The following step we have resolve.

1. Search programs and files in start menu in `cmd`.
2. Right click `cmd` icon with `Run As Administrator` to open window command prompt.
3. Goto postgres directory `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\pgAdmin 4\bin` using cd command in command prompt or set environment variable
4. Execute `pgAdmin4` command.

Let us know if you have problem again.

Comment: it is still there

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
I use PostgreSQL 10.5

1. Go to C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\pgAdmin 4\bin
2. Right click on pgAdmin and choose "run as an administrator".

Answer (score 0):

I echoes the same.

1. Restart your system after installation.
2. running pgAdmin4  with right click - System Administrator solves my issue. Nothing wrong with setup.