# pgadmin4 shows the error, The application server couldn't be contacted on centos7

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

pgadmin4 is showing the error,

> The application server couldn't be contacted

on centos7.

[Screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ntOU.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't execute pgAdmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43513872/cant-execute-pgadmin4)

Comment: No, this is for Centos 7